# DSum Object Required in Access

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

I have a subform in Access 2010 that lists the costs associated with different parts of a project. On another page, I have a `TotalValue` field that takes the sum of the costs for each project, and multiplies it by 1,000,000. Originally, I had just `Parent.[TotalValue] = Me.Est_Value.Value * 1000000`, but that didn't sum the costs. So I tried adding a `DSum`, but it's giving be a runtime error `424: Object Required` at the `DSum` line.

```
Private Sub Est_Value_AfterUpdate()

Me.Recalc
Parent.[TotalValue] = DSum(Projects.EstValue, 
       Projects, Projects.ProjNo = Activity.ProjNo) * 1000000
Parent.[UpdatedCosts] = Date
Parent![Updated Costs].Requery
Parent!Text263.Requery

End Sub
```

I'm not really sure what's wrong with it, so I would appreciate any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't really have any working examples of this.  But based off of what I am reading here: http://www.techonthenet.com/access/functions/domain/dsum.php

It should look more like this:

```
Me.Parent.[TotalValue] = DSum("EstValue", "Projects", "Projects.ProjNo = " & Activity.ProjNo) * 1000000
```

This is assuming `Activity.ProjNo` is a form property and that `Projects.ProjNo` is an numeric field.

Update: From further discussion the `Activity.ProjNo` was not the control that contained the `ProjNo` value and it was `MFProjectsSubform.ProjNo` instead.  So the code should look like:

```
Me.Parent.[TotalValue] = DSum("EstValue", "Projects", "Projects.ProjNo = " & MFProjectsSubform.ProjNo) * 1000000
```

Comment: Try to just assign it to a variable and that will tell you if you are just having a Parent reference issue.

Comment: I tried that, and it's giving me `Run-Time Error 2471:The expression you entered as a query parameter produced this error: Activity.ProjNo.`

Comment: What exactly is `Activity.ProjNo`?  I had just assumed it was a control but now it doesn't seem like that.  I feel like you are looking for something more like `Me.ProjNo` instead.

Comment: That still gives the same error. I'm not as familiar with Access as I wish I was, but `ProjNo` is like an ID for each project. I don't know if it's a control or not, but there's a few places in other subs that has `Me.Controls("GWP")`. I also have `"Projects.ProjNo = Activity.ProjNo"` in a few places and it works there.

Comment: I think that would work find if you were running a query.  Though right now you are just using a DSum, which is used to sum up a specific field based on a criteria.  So basically `"Projects.ProjNo = " & Activity.ProjNo` needs to translate to something like: "Projects.ProjNo = 1234" and since `Activity.ProjNo` seems like it is just a field on a table won't work.  Which is causing your error message.  You need to find a field on your subform that references your current `ProjNo` and use that instead.

Comment: @AxxieD No problem glad I could help, can you let me know what the control was so I can update my answer for future users?

Comment: It was MFProjectsSubform; my main form is called MainForm. So the control was `MFProjectsSubform.ProjNo`.